# Windows XP / Outlook 2003 error messages

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2003

**Can anyone help with this issue? I am trying to help someone and could use some expertise.**

**Error Message #1:**

Microsoft Office Small Business Edition 2003

With CD icon

"The feature you are trying to use is on a CD-ROM or other removable disk that is not available.

Insert the 'Microsoft Office Small Business Edition 2003' disk and click OK.

Use source: Microsoft Office Small Business Edition 2003"

1st got this message after CD was inserted to recover partial file STDP11N. Recovered STDP11N, however, still receiving pop up window with error message each time outlook opens. Had accidentally cleaned up old programs and suddenly this was missing. Reinstalled Microsoft Office Small Business Edition 2003 using install CD. Outlook worked buit keep getting error message pop up each time I open Outlook.

Hit ok.

**Error Message #2:**

The path 'Microsoft Office Small Business Edition 2003' cannot be found. Verify that you have access to this location and try again, or try to find the installation package 'STDP11N.MSI' in a folder from which you can install the product Microsoft Office Small Business Edition 2003."

Hit ok.

Back to error message #1

Hit close window

**Error message #3:**

Error 1706. Setup cannot find the required files. Check your connection to the network, or CD-ROM drive. For other potential solutions to this problem, see C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\ OFFICE11\1033\SETUP.CHM

**Error message #4**

I'd created a file under D: drive on an external drive. "The path specified for the file D:...etc.. .pst is not valid.

Hit ok.

Brings up window to look in My Documents.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you reinstalling using the same CD-ROM drive letter that you originally installed from?  The installation may be looking in the original source path, and if that's changed it may not like it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Office is confused. I think your best bet, given how complex MS Office installations are, is to uninstall it completely, then install Office again. To avoid this sort of thing in the future, always perform a custom install, and for each component, either install it or don't install it; don't tell it to "run from disc when needed".  The reason for that should be fairly obvious by now.  Further, don't install any feature from Business Edition source if it's in any way a trial or demo.

Comment: Yes, I would guess that this is probably a mixture of 'Install on first use' together with a Windows Update that went wrong. Do things in order: Uninstall Office, reboot, re-install, reboot, Windows Update, reboot, see if it works. To completely uninstall Office, see also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301 and http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-2003-resource-kit/office-removal-wizard-HA001140177.aspx.